# Is there a difference between mac and windows databases?

Tags: iphone, sql, windows, database, macos

I am writing an iphone application;I want to learn that is there a downside if i do it with windows?I am going to implement that database into a server and send sql queries with iphone.

Comment: You can't develop and iPhone App on Windows, unless you're using something like Adobe's new flash re-compiler.  You can build a web site targeted for iPhones, but would almost never run on a mac.

Comment: I just make the database on windows not all program i have mac for programing iphone application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is slightly vague as there are many databases some cross platform and some platform specific.

It would depend on the database you decide to use. You can't run MSSQL on a MAC. MYSQL is cross platform and work would on both. I imagine the performance would be pretty similar and the sql scripts would be the same.

Comment: Didn't you mean you can run MySQL on Mac? Or did you mean: You can't run MySQL on iOS. Which is true. iOS only supports SQLite in the default SDK.

Comment: I just send quarries from iphone to the real database stays on the server which is http://something.com i am not going to create a database inside iphone

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're asking if running your backbone on a Windows or Mac server makes any difference when creating an iPhone application.

The short answer is no, it doesn't matter what backbone you're using. If you're accessing the db using web services, it most definitely doesn't matter at all.

However, if you're accessing the database directly, you should be sure that you have the proper iPhone libraries available for the DBMS you want to use (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server etc.). If you have crappy libraries, you'll probably run into a lot of trouble.

**So to sum up**:

- Windows or Mac server makes no difference
- Make sure you have good iPhone libraries if accessing the database directly

Hope that helps.